# PHP : How do I add a week without using the strtotime function?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm hoping that my concern will be answered as soon as possible. :) So here it is: I'm having a hard time solving this problem, as shown below:

```
$beg_week = "2014 - 49"; //yyyy - w
$stop_wk = "2015 - 5"
while($beg_week <= $stop_wk)
{
    /* do logic to add week in the format "yyyy - w", but also
     * have to consider the year */
    $beg_week = ''; 

}
```

So, how can I add a week in a 'yyyy - w' format, without using `strtotime()`?

Comment: how you loop these two values? there is no compare (int) values

Comment: Your beginning week is after your stop week therefore this would never be true

Comment: for what reasons wouldn't you use strtotime with dates and times? it seems it was invented for such.. And, besides, you're currently comparing two strings.. At least use the date object..

Comment: Sorry, but the stop_wk was meant to be 2015 instead. Not 2014. Anyway, $beg_wk and $stop_wk is just a sample data but it's actually dates from db that were formatted into a yyyy - w convention.

Comment: So? You can still use strtotime functions on that format. Or manipulate it so it's possible anyhow. There is no real reason not to do it besides subjective reasons. And even then it's a bad subjective reason not to.

Comment: @TomKriek, Actually you cannot use strtotime with that format, I think. And yes you're right, just manipulate it then use the function afterwards. Anyway, I think Agi Hammerthief's idea will be perfect for this.

Comment: You can use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` on a date field in MySQL, so that PHP doesn't have to parse the date. I assume other SQL dialects have similar functions.

Comment: @briosheje and Tom Kriek: `strtotime()` essentially guesses what the component parts of a date string are, based on values alone. Given that there are many possible combinations of date, it often guesses incorrectly. Take the string "05-05-05", for example. Is the first value the month, day, year or hour? If it's a year, what century? Same goes for the second and third parts. A function that takes a format is better; it increases the chances of getting a correct timestamp.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief: There are many ways to accomplish what the OP asked, if he didn't want to use strtotime with mktime (as an example) he could at least have used the comfortable date prototype, he is currently comparing STRINGS, that's what I was saying above, I've never said that strtotime was the best solution in such a case, despite it would have perfectly worked with the OP example ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert your start and end times to timestamps using `date_parse_from_format()` and `mktime()`. Alternatively, use an SQL function like MySQL's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` if retrieving data from a datetime field.
2. Use `date_parse_from_format()` to break the date into its components.
3. Use `mktime()` to get a timestamp
4. Add a week's worth of seconds (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
5. Use `date()` to output the next week.

**Note:** `date_parse*()` won't log/store an error in the returned array if you have more than 29 or 28 days in February (for a leap or regular year, respectively). This might/might not matter, depending on what you're using it for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to jump through hoops with date() and mktime() for this. The DateTime classes can handle it simply and cleanly, something like this should [work](http://3v4l.org/BfTFH) for you:-

```
$beg_week = (new \DateTime())->setISODate(2014, 49);
$stop_week = (new \DateTime())->setISODate(2015, 5);
$interval = new \DateInterval('P7D');

while($beg_week < $stop_week){
    echo $beg_week->format('Y-m-d') . "<br/>\n";
    $beg_week->add($interval);
}
```

Comment: Actually I've tried to manipulate the date by using date() function and get the the date of the Monday of a specific week, then used strtotime to add 1 week on the given date then format it again to a  'Y - W' so the loop would run smoothly. And it works well, but the problem occurs when the Monday of the first week is on the previous year. Anyway thanks for this! Will try this one Sir.

Comment: @NeilVincentCruz "problem occurs when the Monday of the first week is on the previous year". This method will deal with that.

Comment: @NeilVincentCruz This years first week had its Monday in 2014, that isn't a problem. http://3v4l.org/iRLe2

Comment: yup i can actually get the "Y-m-d" format out of date that is in "Y - W" format, but when I used to add 1 week using strtotime() function, then that's the problem right now. Hoping for your reply Sir. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It turned out the same problem

Comment: Anyway Sir @vascowhite, I've got it already! :) Please refer to my posted answer.  Thank you very much! God bless!

Answer (score -1):

Sorry it took so long before I am able to solved and share the method/approach that I used for this matter, since I've got an additional project than this. So what i did was:

First, build a function that gets the max week of a year(thanks to @salathe),

```
function getIsoWeekYear($year)
{
    $date = new DateTime;
    $date->setISODate($year,53);
    return ($date->format("W") === "53" ? 53 : 52);
}
```

Then to increment the value of a week, considering also the given year,

```
$beg_week = "2014 - 50";   //just a sample and not actually a string
$end_week = "2015 - 05";

while($beg_week<=$end_week)
(
    $out_data[] = $beg_week;

    $b_week_exp = explode(" - ",$beg_week);
    $b_yr_temp = $b_week_exp[0];
    $b_wk_temp = $b_week_exp[1];
    $max_wk_of_yr = getIsoWeeksInYear($b_yr_temp);

    $out_year = $b_yr_temp;
    $out_week_no = $b_wk_temp+1;
    if($out_week_no > $max_wk_of_yr)
    {
        $out_year = $b_yr_temp+1;
        $out_week_no = "1";
    }
    $beg_week = $out_year." - ".sprintf("%02s", $out_week_no);
)
```

That's it, if you will print_r the $out_data, you will have an array of,

```
2014 - 50
2014 - 51
2014 - 52
2015 - 01
2015 - 02
2015 - 03
2015 - 04
2015 - 05
```

Well, this logic is what I want, to have loop from $beg_week up to $end_week, because there's also a logic that I am executing in it. A very simple trick, for this very simple problem! :) Sorry, SOMETIMES I am that sluggish not to answer my own question/problem. I hope this one will help to anyone who'll also encounter this same scenario. Thank you!